# How to add 2 MFCC extracted features to a variable?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, mfcc

I am working on signal processing for speaker verification.

I have extracted MFCC features for few wav files using GMM algorithm.

Now, i want to **add any 2 MFCC features to another variable**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.. Please can you elaborate on the "to another variable"?

Comment: See, there are hundreds of MFCC vectors generated and it will be stored in the form of a file.

My requirement is to add the contents of 2 of these files.